# Adding a row to a table dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have this table and I want to be able to add rows to it dynamically using Jquery but I'm falling so far, I already have a loop in place for the added rows, I just need the script that goes with it. (I'm using a MVC pattern design)

My code for the loop :

```
<?php
     $viewTableRows = array_merge($device->tableRows, array(new tableRow()));
     foreach ($viewTableRows as $i => $row) { 
  ?>
```

an example of a td:

```
<td>
       <?php echo $htmlRenderer->getProperHtmlForInputText(
           SheetTableOperator::SHEET_POSITION .  "[$i]",
           $row->position);
       ?>
</td>
```

[image: an Image of my table]

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to add data dynamically.

```
        <button id='mybtn'>Add row</button>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
           $(document).on("click",'#mybtn',function(){  

                 var $mytable = $('#table').find("tbody");

                  $last_row = $mytable.find("tr:last");

                  $new_row = $last_row.clone();

                  $last_row.after($new_row);

           });    


</script>
```

Comment: Yes , but how I  can implement it in my case ? using my loop

Comment: @NoureddineBrahmi there is a different event in jquery you can add dynamically in any row or column.

Comment: @NoureddineBrahmi if you still have a doubt please add your code in jsfiddle I will help you out from this.

Comment: This is my jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/18tedjt4/1/)  and thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @NoureddineBrahmi check my answer I updated it also you can check js fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/18tedjt4/10/)

Comment: Yes using a variable could be vert helpful in my case , but can I implement the loop I have in my Question ? if yes how ?

Comment: @NoureddineBrahmi No you can't implement that way because PHP execute before script.

Comment: @NoureddineBrahmi Explain me your whole case you want to add row dynamically but when?
When user submit some form or fill data ?
currently i have lots of confusion in your question

Comment: I want the user to add a row when he clicks on a button under my current table ( see the  question ) the thing is my TDs are complicated and I already have a loop in place , and I tried using the append method but it was impossible ..

Comment: @NoureddineBrahmi use below code to copy  your table row

var $mytable = $('#table').find("tbody");

$last_row = $mytable.find("tr:last");

$new_row = $last_row.clone();

$last_row.after($new_row);

Answer (score 0):

1. Method 1

   ```
   var currentEletd;

   $('table').append("<tr class='tr'></tr>").after(
       function() {
           var ele = $('.tr', this);
           currentEletd = (ele[ele.length - 1]);
   });

   $(currentEleth).append(("<td>" + [your value] + "</td>"));
   ```
2. Method 2

   ```
   mytbody=$("<tbody></tbody>");
   mytr = $("<tr></tr>");
   mytr.append("<td></td>");

   $('table').append(mytbody);
   ```

Comment: I like your first method , but my table is quiet complicated , i have more than 10 tds and in each td a big load of information , so I'm afraid this won't be possible or my code will be really messy.

Comment: use loop to generate td